# Inserting user input data into sqlite3 in python

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy

I cannot insert data into sqlite3 database using python...please look into the code i wrote and tell me all the defects in my program .. i am a beginner  in programming..

i am receiving error

```
btn = Button(text="Save", on_press=self.add_question(qst.text, ans.text))
 TypeError: add_question() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

```
import sqlite3
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class qbApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2)
        lbl = Label(text="Question :")
        qst = TextInput()
        lbl1 = Label(text="Answer :")
        ans = TextInput()
        btn = Button(text="Save", on_press= add_question(qst.text, ans.text))

        layout.add_widget(lbl)
        layout.add_widget(qst)
        layout.add_widget(lbl1)
        layout.add_widget(ans)
        layout.add_widget(btn)

        return layout

    def add_question(qst, ans):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('KSFE.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        sql = """INSERT INTO qb (question, answer) 
             VALUES (?,?);"""

        c.execute(sql, (qst, ans))
        print("Data added")

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    qbApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to either pass `self` to `add_question` or declare it as a static method:

```
# option 1

    def add_question(self, qst, ans):
        pass


# option 2:

    @staticmethod
    def add_question(qst, ans):
        pass
```

Also, in your code snippet you have a small error: `on_press=self.add_question(qst.text, ans.text)`

Take a look at [Example](https://stackabuse.com/pythons-classmethod-and-staticmethod-explained/#alongerexample) for an example

Comment: Sir, I tried both options but now i am getting an error like this     --- File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 421, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind
 AssertionError: None is not callable